# Help Me "in_category" with echo?

Tags: categories

if i usage below code, that show category id "**20**"

```
<?php echo $ct_portfoliocatid; ?>
```

But when i usage "**in_category**" for generate category ID '20'. Like this:

```
<?php if (in_category('<?php echo $ct_portfoliocatid; ?>')) : ?> 
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/portfolio.php'); ?> 
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The code did not work, please help me.

Comment: This is a pure PHP question. Your code is broken-- badly broken. Among other things, single quoted strings do not expand, and there is no need for the php tags. Try : `in_category($ct_portfoliocatid)` Voting to close as off-topic per the [faq].

Comment: I have test like this: **<?php if (in_category($ct_portfoliocatid)) : ?>** but still not work

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `in_category` correctly, your code modified as per my comment should work. That is...

```
if (in_category($ct_portfoliocatid)) :
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/portfolio.php');
else :
endif;
```

You don't need all those messy opening and closing PHP tags so I removed them and I don't know why you have an `else` at all.

[From the Codex for `in_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category):

> Tests if the current post (or any specified post) is assigned to any
>   of the specified categories.
>
> in_category() considers only the categories a post is directly
>   assigned to (the checked categories in Write/Edit Post panel), not the
>   parents of the assigned categories (but see Testing if a post is in a
>   descendant category below).
>
> This tag can be used to test the current post within The Loop or
>   (since Version 2.7) outside the Loop during a single post request. You
>   can use it anywhere if you specify which post you want to test.

So, if that code is in the Loop (you did not supply the second parameter so it defaults to the current post in the Loop), and if the category is directly assigned to the post and not a parent category of a category assigned to the post, that code should work, and does work when I try it. Of course, `$ct_portfoliocatid` also has to be set correctly and I have no way to know if it is.

Again, your original code is badly broken but perhaps another issue is that you are not using the function correctly.

Comment: I create "**Theme Option**" in wp admin.

This is piece of my code for create a form on "Theme Option" :

 `array( "name" => "CATEGORY",
   "type" => "title"),
   
 array( "type" => "open"),   

 array( "name" => "Portfolio Category ID",
   "desc" => "Insert your 'Portfolio Category ID' in here",
   "id" => $shortname."_portfoliocatid",
   "std" => "",
   "type" => "text")`


When I go to "**Theme option**" I enter category ID "**20**" on the Form.

Comment: I load the category ID using this code: 

`<?php echo $ct_portfoliocatid; ?>`

Comment: And now i want that code on here:

    `<?php if (in_category('<?php echo $ct_portfoliocatid; ?>')) : ?> 
    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/portfolio.php'); ?> 
    <?php else : ?>
    Default category
    <?php endif; ?>`


Forgive me if my english language not good.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all of this code and additional information.